# Phonegap JQTouch Joomla and MySQL application

Tags: mysql, xml, joomla, cordova, jqtouch

I am working on a project and it needs to accomplish the following:

1. A user logs into a joomla
2. Makes a change to some of their profile
3. This new information updates in the
   database

Up to this point joomla will do everything, so the question is how do I take the information from the database and call it into a phonegap app.  I am using phonegap and jqtouch for the app, and joomla with jomsocial for the update side.

I cannot have the app open into just a mobile version of the website because apple will reject it from the store.  I need this solution to work for people to make updates to their profile, and these updates will automatically post to their app.  All users input data on the same site, and share a database.  Each profile however will have a different app that is released to the markets, so right now I am focusing on a template framework that can easily be changed to the users portion of the database.

From my understanding the php files stay on the server to process information.  The big question is how do i call this information into a phonegap app?

Comment: I can't answer your question as I haven't used phonegap before, however I have read some stuff about it and the major hurdle with getting your app approved with Apple is ensuring something is displayed to the user of the app when they don't have internet connection. Essentially you can have a app that points to a website but you need to ensure that something nice is displayed when the user cannot access your website.

Comment: Well I have an update in what I expect to do to get this to work.  I created a php script that is placed on the server, the function of this script goes to the database and pulls all the relevant items that I need and stores this into an XML file. So the revision of my initial question would be: How do I take variables from and XML sheet and display it in HTML.  Ex: the name of the member is stored into a variable in the XML sheet. When the app opens I want the index.HTML file in the app to just pull name from the variable in the XML and display this at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

To display XML as HTML you need to parse it through an XSLT stylesheet. This transforms your XML nodes into HTML. Of course, you could just use a PHP XML parser. I think there's one bundled with Joomla, but there are lots out there.

I was going to suggest using a Joomla plugin to push the data over to the Phonegap app. There are lots of events that are fired when an account is created and you could manipulate that.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is local, Jeepstone is correct. If it is not, how are you going to get it? To do this without running into cross domain issues, I suggest you try out this jQuery plugin on the phonegap side of things ... http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/ . So to take advantage of that nifty tool, you will adjust the public functions in this script to echo back json_encoded array. With which you can then do as you want on the phonegap side of things.

Ya Apple wants your app to not be useless without internet. But it is straightforward to create your index.html to show the user something. Use the failure and success functions in the jsonp library to show connection problems if necessary.